# Multiplayer coins

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Having a slight issue getting some coins to generate multiplayer using eureca.io websockets. I've got the players working multiplayer and from remote connections but I can't seem to get the coins to generate across the connection so they appear in the same place on all the players connections. I'm using phaser to generate the game and eureca and engine for my web connection. I've got the coins to spawn on the page with no problems, but whenever a new player joins, the coin always displays in a different place, I wondering how I can make them generate across the connection. My game code is below:

Game Code

```
var myId = 0;
var background;
var blueSquare;
var player;
var coins;
var goldCoin;
var squareList;
var coinList;
var cursors;
var score;
var highScore;

var ready = false;
var eurecaServer;

var eurecaClientSetup = function () {
var eurecaClient = new Eureca.Client();
eurecaClient.ready(function (proxy) {       
    eurecaServer = proxy;
});
eurecaClient.exports.setId = function (id) 
{
    myId = id;
    create();
    eurecaServer.handshake();
    ready = true;
}   
eurecaClient.exports.kill = function (id)
{   
    if (squareList[id]) {
        squareList[id].kill();
        console.log('Player has left the game ', id, squareList[id]);
    }
}   
eurecaClient.exports.spawnBlueSquare = function (i, x, y)
{
    if (i == myId) return;

    console.log('A new player has joined the game');
    var blsq = new BlueSquare(i, game, blueSquare);
    squareList[i] = blsq;
}
eurecaClient.exports.spawnCoins = function (c, x, y)
{   
    console.log('A coin has been generated');
    var cn = new GenerateCoin(c, game, coin);
    coinList[c] = cn;
}
eurecaClient.exports.updateState = function (id, state)
{
    if (squareList[id]) {
        squareList[id].cursor = state;
        squareList[id].blueSquare.x = state.x;
        squareList[id].blueSquare.y = state.y;
        squareList[id].blueSquare.angle = state.angle;
        squareList[id].update();

        coinList.cursor = state;
        coinList.blueSquare.x = state.x;
        coinList.blueSquare.y = state.y;
        coinList.update();
    }
 }
}

BlueSquare = function (index, game, player) {
this.cursor = {
    left:false,
    right:false,
    up:false,
    down:false, 
}

this.input = {
    left:false,
    right:false,
    up:false,
    down:false,
}

var x = 0;
var y = 0;

this.game = game;
this.player = player;
this.currentSpeed = 0;

this.isBlue = true;

this.blueSquare = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'blueSquare');
this.blueSquare.anchor.set(0.5);

this.blueSquare.id = index;
game.physics.enable(this.blueSquare, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
this.blueSquare.body.immovable = false;
this.blueSquare.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
this.blueSquare.body.setSize(34, 34, 0, 0);

this.blueSquare.angle = 0;

game.physics.arcade.velocityFromRotation(this.blueSquare.rotation, 0,         this.blueSquare.body.velocity);
}

BlueSquare.prototype.update = function () {
var inputChanged = (
    this.cursor.left != this.input.left ||
    this.cursor.right != this.input.right ||
    this.cursor.up != this.input.up ||
    this.cursor.down != this.input.down
);
if (inputChanged)
{   
    if (this.blueSquare.id == myId)
    {
        this.input.x = this.blueSquare.x;
        this.input.y = this.blueSquare.y;
        this.input.angle = this.blueSquare.angle;

        eurecaServer.handleKeys(this.input);    
    }
}
if (this.cursor.left)
    {
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.x = -250;
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.y = 0;
    }
    else if (this.cursor.right)
    {
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.x = 250;
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.y = 0;

    }
    else if (this.cursor.down)
    {
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.x = 0;
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.y = 250;
    }   
    else if (this.cursor.up)
    {
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.x = 0;
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.y = -250;
    }
    else 
    {
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.x = 0;
        this.blueSquare.body.velocity.y = 0;
    }
}

BlueSquare.prototype.kill = function () {
this.alive = false;
this.blueSquare.kill();
}

GenerateCoin = function (game, goldCoin) {

this.game = game;
this.goldCoin = goldCoin;

x = 0;
y = 0;

this.coins = game.add.sprite(x, y, 'coin');
game.physics.enable(this.coins, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
this.coins.body.immovable = true;
this.coins.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
this.coins.body.setSize(16, 16, 0, 0);
}

window.onload = function() {
function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
{
    var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;
    function twoDigits( n )
    {
        return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
    }
    function updateTimer()
    {
        msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
        if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
            element.innerHTML = "Game Over!";
        } else {
            time = new Date( msLeft );
            hours = time.getUTCHours();
            mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
            element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
            setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
        }
    }
    element = document.getElementById( elementName );
    endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
    updateTimer();
}countdown( "countdown", 5, 0 );
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(700, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'Square Hunt', { preload:  preload, create: eurecaClientSetup, update: update, render: render });

function preload () {
game.load.spritesheet('coin', 'assets/coin.png', 18, 18);
game.load.image('blueSquare', 'assets/blue-square.png');
game.load.image('redSquare', 'assets/red-square.png');
game.load.image('earth', 'assets/sand.png');
}

function create () {
game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 1500, 1500);
game.stage.disableVisibilityChange  = true;

background = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'earth');
background.fixedToCamera = true;

squareList = {};

player = new BlueSquare(myId, game, blueSquare);
squareList[myId] = player;
blueSquare = player.blueSquare;
blueSquare.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 650);
blueSquare.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 650);

blueSquare.bringToTop();

game.camera.follow(blueSquare);
game.camera.deadzone = new Phaser.Rectangle(150, 150, 500, 300);
game.camera.focusOnXY(0, 0);

cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

coinList = {};

goldCoin = new GenerateCoin(game, coins);
coinList = goldCoin;
coins = goldCoin.coins;
coins.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 650);
coins.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 650);

coins.bringToTop();
}

function update () {
if (!ready) return;

game.physics.arcade.collide(blueSquare, coins);

player.input.left = cursors.left.isDown;
player.input.right = cursors.right.isDown;
player.input.up = cursors.up.isDown;
player.input.down = cursors.down.isDown;

player.input.fire = game.input.activePointer.isDown;
player.input.tx = game.input.x+ game.camera.x;
player.input.ty = game.input.y+ game.camera.y;

background.tilePosition.x = -game.camera.x;
background.tilePosition.y = -game.camera.y; 

for (var i in squareList)
{
    if (!squareList[i]) continue;
    var curBlue = squareList[i].blueSquare;
    for (var j in squareList)
    {
        if (!squareList[j]) continue;
        if (j!=i) 
        {
            var targetBlue = squareList[j].blueSquare;
        }
        if (squareList[j].isBlue)
        {
            squareList[j].update();
        }           
    }
}
}

function test(){
console.log('collsion');
}

function render () {}
```

Server.js Files

```
var express = require('express')
, app = express(app)
, server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var clients = {};
var EurecaServer = require('eureca.io').EurecaServer;
var eurecaServer = new EurecaServer({allow:['setId', 'spawnBlueSquare', 'spawnCoins', 'kill', 'updateState']});
eurecaServer.attach(server);

eurecaServer.onConnect(function (conn) {    
console.log('New Client id=%s ', conn.id, conn.remoteAddress);

var remote = eurecaServer.getClient(conn.id);    

clients[conn.id] = {id:conn.id, remote:remote}
remote.setId(conn.id);  
});

eurecaServer.onConnectionLost(function (conn) {
console.log('connection lost ... will try to reconnect');
});

eurecaServer.onDisconnect(function (conn) {    
console.log('Client disconnected ', conn.id);

var removeId = clients[conn.id].id;

delete clients[conn.id];

for (var c in clients)
{
    var remote = clients[c].remote;
    remote.kill(conn.id);
}   
});

eurecaServer.exports.handshake = function()
{
for (var c in clients)
{
    var remote = clients[c].remote;
    for (var cc in clients)
    {       
        var x = clients[cc].laststate ? clients[cc].laststate.x:  0;
        var y = clients[cc].laststate ? clients[cc].laststate.y:  0;

        remote.spawnBlueSquare(clients[cc].id, x, y);   
    }
}
}

eurecaServer.exports.handleKeys = function (keys) {
var conn = this.connection;
var updatedClient = clients[conn.id];

for (var c in clients)
{
    var remote = clients[c].remote;
    remote.updateState(updatedClient.id, keys);

    clients[c].laststate = keys;
}
}
server.listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of generating coins randomly positioned on each client, you could generate this random position(x and y) in server side(on conexion event) and then send this position to all clients so they can generate the coin in the same position.

Comment: Ah great that makes sense, all this server javascript is new to me so its making my head explode ever so slightly